# Access elements of an R6 class that instantiates another R6 class

Tags: r, r6

Say I have a class `SimpleClass` and one of the methods of that class can return an object of another class, e.g.

```r
SimpleClass <- R6::R6Class(
  "SimpleClass",
  public = list(
    initialize = function() {
      private$a <- 1
    },
    cls_two = function() SimpleClass2$new()
  ),
  private = list(
    a = numeric()
  )
)
```

Where `SimpleClass2` is

```r
SimpleClass2 <- R6::R6Class(
  "SimpleClass2",
  public = list(
    initialize = function() {
      private$b <- 2
    },
    get_a = function() private$a
  ),
  private = list(
    b = numeric()
  )
)
```

Here, if I were instantiate `SimpleClass` and call the method `cls_two()`, the resulting object will not have access to the elements of the first object unless I pass them on. Is there a way for the secondary class to access elements of the first class?

```r
first <- SimpleClass$new()
second <- first$cls_two()
second$get_a()
# NULL
```

Note that I do not want to use inheritance in the traditional sense because I do not want to reinstantiate the first class. I would also prefer not to have to pass on all of the objects to `SimpleClass2$new()`.

Comment: I've had a similar problem recently and solved it via a shared environment. Basically create an environment in SimpleClass init method and pass that environment to the second object of class SimpleClass2.Another option would be to directly pass SimpleClass  "self" to the object you instantiate with SimpleClass2$new(). Let me know if you need an example and I can create it.

Comment: Yes that’s not a bad idea. I had already considered a shared environment within the package, however within the class is a good idea! I’d be surprised if R6 doesn’t have an inbuilt way to do this though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extend `SimpleClass2`’s constructor to take an object of type `SimpleClass`, and pass `self` when calling the constructor in `SimpleClass::cls_two`:

```
SimpleClass2 <- R6::R6Class(
  "SimpleClass2",
  public = list(
    initialize = function(obj) {
      private$b <- 2
      private$obj <- obj
    },
    get_a = function() private$obj
  ),
  private = list(
    b = numeric(),
    obj = NULL
  )
)
```

Comment: Isn't this the same answer? I guess it's neater though. Don't want to make unnecessary R6 objects if a NULL will suffice.

Comment: @AllanCameron Yeah it’s pretty much the same. When I submitted the answer there wasn’t yet any — I actually had it written and just wanted to try it, and then came back and pressed “submit”.

Comment: So is there no other way than passing self and/or private? Because I may wish to be able to instantiate SimpleClass2 separately with different arguments. It’s a shame I have to explicitly pass self and I can’t just access it.

Comment: @nathaneastwood you _can_ instantiate SimpleClass2 separately, Just have a default NULL for obj so that this only gets used by the constructor in SimpleClass. What's the problem with passing `self` from the constructor? You're passing by reference anyway, so this is a very cheap copy. Plus the interface it gives is identical to the one you wanted in your example.

Comment: To me, it won’t be very user friendly having a parameter that is NULL by default and is only required when called by another class. I maybe need to think about my interface a bit more.

Comment: In my answer I give the alternative: SimpleClass2 always contains a SimpleClass object, but it is empty by default. If you don't have a SimpleClass of some kind in a SimpleClass2 how does having a `get_a` method in SimpleClass2 make sense?

Comment: Yup. I shouldn't respond to StackOverflow when I have been coding more than 14 hours! It wouldn't make sense indeed.

This answer suited my needs in the end as I didn't want to reinstantiate the class and I can get what I need from `obj`.

Answer (score 2):

You can make SimpleClass2 have a member that is a Simpleclass and have an option to pass a simpleclass in its constructor:

```
SimpleClass <- R6::R6Class(
  "SimpleClass",
  public = list(
    initialize = function() {
      private$a <- 1
    },
    cls_two = function() SimpleClass2$new(self)
  ),
  private = list(
    a = numeric()
  )
)

SimpleClass2 <- R6::R6Class(
  "SimpleClass2",
  public = list(
    initialize = function(Simp1 = SimpleClass$new()) {
      private$a <- Simp1
      private$b <- 2
    },
    get_a = function() private$a
  ),
  private = list(
    a = SimpleClass$new(),
    b = numeric()
  )
)
```

Which works like this:

```r
first <- SimpleClass$new()
second <- first$cls_two()
second$get_a()
#> <SimpleClass>
#>   Public:
#>     clone: function (deep = FALSE) 
#>     cls_two: function () 
#>     initialize: function () 
#>   Private:
#>     a: 1
```